# Homotopy group for a certain subset of Euclidean space

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $X_{2,n} = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{n} \times \mathbb{R}^n : x \text{ and } y \text{ are linearly independent} \}$. How can I compute the homotopy group $\pi_2(X_{2,n})$ for $n \geq 3$?

Comment: For $n\geq 5$, you can see that $\pi_2(X_{2,n})$ is trivial from the long exact sequence of the fiber bundle $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\mathbb{R}\rightarrow X_{2,n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}$ that you get from projecting onto the $x$ coordinate.

Comment: For $n=3$, it appears straightforward to compute $\pi_2(X_{2,n})$ by the same technique, but for $n=4$ I have trouble visualizing the relevant boundary map. I'm pretty sure I've seen this calculation before, so maybe it is in Milnor and Stasheff.

Comment: It might help to know that $X_{2,n}$ is (homotopy equivalent to) the Stiefel manifold $V_2(\mathbb{R}^n)$, which can be identified with the unit tangent bundle to $S^{n-1}$.